# Why doesn't my Java preferences code work on all computers?

Tags: java, preferences

I am using preferences to save the location of a JFrame so when it appears again it should be in the same place as it was previously exited. I have it working on my computer but it seems that it doesn't work on 3 other computers that I have tested. I exported my project as a jar file and had people execute the program using the jar file.

The location of the frame isn't saved, it will always appear in the top left corner of the screen.

This is my first time using preferences, I looked through the API multiple times and I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. Could someone please explain why it only works on my computer?

The preferences settings are at the bottom of the class.

**SSCCE :**

```
public class PreferencesTest implements ActionListener {
private JButton wrongButton, level1Button, level2Button, level3Button,
        level4Button, level5Button, dontInterruptButton, reviewCardButton;
private JLabel frontTextLabel, reverseTextLabel, frontLabel;
private JPanel frontOfCardPanel, reverseOfCardPanel, buttonPanel,
        reverseButtonPanel, reverseTextPanel, frontLabelPanel;
private JFrame frame;
private String windowTitle;
private int windowX;
private int windowY;
private Preferences preferences = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new PreferencesTest();
        }
    });
}


public PreferencesTest() {

    this.windowX = getPreferences().getInt("window_x", -1);
    this.windowY = getPreferences().getInt("window_y", -1);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frontOfCardPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    reverseOfCardPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    wrongButton = new JButton("Wrong");
    level1Button = new JButton("Almost");
    level2Button = new JButton("OK");
    level3Button = new JButton("Good");
    level4Button = new JButton("Great");
    level5Button = new JButton("Excellent");
    dontInterruptButton = new JButton("Don't interrupt this program");
    reviewCardButton = new JButton("Review");

    frontTextLabel = new JLabel("test", JLabel.CENTER);
    reverseTextLabel = new JLabel("test", JLabel.CENTER);
    frontLabel = new JLabel("test", JLabel.CENTER);

    frontTextLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    frontLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    reverseTextLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    reverseButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    reverseTextPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    reverseButtonPanel.add(wrongButton);
    reverseButtonPanel.add(level1Button);
    reverseButtonPanel.add(level2Button);
    reverseButtonPanel.add(level3Button);
    reverseButtonPanel.add(level4Button);
    reverseButtonPanel.add(level5Button);

    frontLabelPanel = new JPanel();
    frontLabelPanel.add(frontLabel);

    frontOfCardPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frontOfCardPanel.add(frontLabelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setContentPane(frontOfCardPanel);

    reverseTextPanel.add(reverseTextLabel);
    reverseTextPanel.add(frontTextLabel);

    buttonPanel.add(reviewCardButton);
    buttonPanel.add(dontInterruptButton);

    reverseOfCardPanel.add(reverseTextPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    reverseOfCardPanel.add(reverseButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    wrongButton.addActionListener(this);
    level1Button.addActionListener(this);
    level2Button.addActionListener(this);
    level3Button.addActionListener(this);
    level4Button.addActionListener(this);
    level5Button.addActionListener(this);
    dontInterruptButton.addActionListener(this);
    reviewCardButton.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    frame.setSize(500, 220);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.toFront();
    frame.repaint();

    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
            setWindowXY();

            frame.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    frame.setLocation(windowX, windowY);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionCommand() == "Review") {
        frame.remove(frontOfCardPanel);
        frame.setContentPane(reverseOfCardPanel);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Wrong") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(0);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Almost") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(1);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "OK") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(2);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Good") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(3);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Great") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(4);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Excellent") {
        setWindowXY();
        System.exit(1);
        flashcardAction(5);
    } else if (event.getActionCommand() == "Don't interrupt this program") {
        System.exit(1);
        System.out.println(" window title in event = " + windowTitle);
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }
}

public void flashcardAction(int userResponse) {
    System.out.println(frame.getLocationOnScreen());
    setVisible(false);
}



public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {

    frame.setVisible(visible);
}

// ////// preferences

public Preferences getPreferences() {
    if (preferences == null) {
        preferences = Preferences
                .systemNodeForPackage(PreferencesTest.class);
    }
    return preferences;
}

public int getWindowX() {
    return windowX;
}

public int getWindowY() {
    return windowY;
}

public void setWindowXY() {
    windowX = frame.getX();
    getPreferences().putInt("window_x", windowX);

    windowY = frame.getY();
    getPreferences().putInt("window_y", windowY);
}
}
```

EDIT: I didn't explain what's wrong with its behaviour.

Comment: So whats the error on the 3 other computers? DO they have a JRE installed

Comment: Define "doesn't work". We need behaviour, stack trace... something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [systemNodeForPackage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29).  This will return the system preferences, not the user preferences.

The reason it's working on one system is probably because you are running it as an admin user there (I'm guessing you're using WinXP or something like that, where it's common to run as an administrator user).  The admin user can write to the system preference tree without issues.

On other, more mature OSes, the system node cannot be written to without elevated access.  The correct approach would be to use the **user node** instead (method [userNodeForPackage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29)).

Java has two seperate preference roots, one for system and one for user.  Use the correct one depending on your situation.  Window position is clearly a user preference.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_preferences_api